# Jason Platten 1234

Tags: hand-history

Question Re playing Texas Holdem

With the below hand - Who wins?? Or is it a Split pot?

Player 1 - Q 7

Player 2 - Q 8

Flop - K Q Q 77

Answer (score 3):

Split pot... It's the best 5 card hand, that's it, nothing else matters. Yes the Q7 has another full house but that makes no difference.

Player 1's best 5 cards:
QQQ77

Player 2's best 5 cards:
QQQ77

There's no better 5 cards with either player.

Comment: What moron downvoted this? It's the right answer.